# os.Getenv and os.LookupEnv don't return the value of $HISTFILE, $HISTSIZE, and $SAVEHIST

Tags: go, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm using `zsh`, and I'm trying to access these environment variables:

```
$ echo $HISTFILE
/home/amir/.zsh_history
$ echo $HISTSIZE
50000
$ echo $SAVEHIST
10000
```

But [`os.LookupEnv`](https://pkg.go.dev/os#LookupEnv) returns `"", false` for all three, and [`os.Getenv`](https://pkg.go.dev/os#Getenv), naturally, returns an empty string:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    histfile, found := os.LookupEnv("HISTFILE")
    if found {
        fmt.Println(histfile)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("$HISTFILE not found")
    }

    histsize, found := os.LookupEnv("HISTSIZE")
    if found {
        fmt.Println(histsize)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("$HISTSIZE not found")
    }

    savehist, found := os.LookupEnv("SAVEHIST")
    if found {
        fmt.Println(savehist)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("$SAVEHIST not found")
    }
}
```

```
$ go run main.go
$HISTFILE not found
$HISTSIZE not found
$SAVEHIST not found
```

Now, if I `export` these variables in `$HOME/.zshrc`:

```
$ grep -iE "histfile|histsize|savehist" $HOME/.zshrc
export HISTFILE="$HOME/.zsh_history"
export HISTSIZE=1000000
export SAVEHIST=1000000
```

Then it works and correct values are returned:

```
$ go run hyst.go
/home/amir/.zsh_history
1000000
1000000
```

When I haven't explicitly exported these variables, the values of `$HISTSIZE` and `$SAVEHIST` are different, but they're not empty. So why do these functions return empty strings for these variables?

Comment: You have to put the variables into the environment, if you want to access them by `os.LookupEnv`. As the name of the function suggests, it accesses the **environment** of your process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `$HISTFILE`, `$HISTSIZE`, and `$SAVEHIST` are not, *by default*, environment variables, but rather simply *shell variables* set by [`oh-my-zsh`](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/12669f29f0843b8b980dd137f150a74511f88842/lib/history.zsh#L29):

```sh
## History file configuration
[ -z "$HISTFILE" ] && HISTFILE="$HOME/.zsh_history"
[ "$HISTSIZE" -lt 50000 ] && HISTSIZE=50000
[ "$SAVEHIST" -lt 10000 ] && SAVEHIST=10000
```

These are the values you see when you use `echo` before using `export` in `$HOME/.zshrc`.

It's important to make a distinction between [environment and shell variables](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26318/environment-variable-vs-shell-variable-whats-the-difference):

- Environment variables are accessible in child processes, but shell variables are not. You can verify this statement by simply creating a child process:

  ```sh
  $ # Child processes don't inherit shell variables
  $ key=value; sh -c 'echo "key=$key"'
  key=

  $ # They do, however, inherit environment variables
  $ export key=value; sh -c 'echo "key=$key"'
  key=value
  ```
- To be able to access a shell variable in the child process, you can `export` it, just as you did in `$HOME/.zshrc`:

  ```sh
  $ key=value; export key; sh -c 'echo "key=$key"'
  key=value
  ```

Now, to see if a specific variable is an environment variable or not, instead of using `echo`, you can directly check the list of [`env`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Env)ironment variables.

```sh
$ env | grep -i "shell"; echo $?
SHELL=/usr/bin/zsh
0
```

So `$SHELL` is, in fact, an environment variable. Now for the history variables:

```sh
$ env | grep -iE "histfile|histsize|savehist"; echo $?
1
```

The exit code is 1, meaning that it failed to find these names in the list of environment variables.